# Angular: How to hit API only if 2+ characters typed

Tags: angular

Have to hit API if we can enter more than 2+ characters only. Below code working fine with from first character. Could you please help me with 2+ characters and some delay time for every click.

.ts

```
subAccountItemObservable: Observable<any>;
   asyncAccountValue: string;
       this.subAccountItemObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
          observer.next(this.asyncAccountValue);
       }).mergeMap((token: string) =>{
       return this.http.get('/testAPI/getTestAPIRecords',{params: {param1: param1}});
 });
```

.html

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input
      id="idsubAccountItemObservable"
      [(ngModel)]="asyncAccountValue"
      [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
      [typeahead]="subAccountItemObservable"
      (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
      (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
      class="form-control searchInput"
      placeholder="Sub Account"
      required
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using? There is no `mergeMap` member function in an `Observable` in the latest version

Comment: Why do you use a `new Observable`? Your code is equivalent to `this.subAccountItemObservable = of(this.asyncAccountValue).pipe(mergeMap((token: string) =>{...`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the string length before you call `next`:

```
subAccountItemObservable: Observable<any>;
asyncAccountValue: string;
this.subAccountItemObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
    if (asyncAccountValue.length > 1)
        observer.next(asyncAccountValue);
}).mergeMap((token: string) => {
    return this.http.get('/testAPI/getTestAPIRecords',{params: {param1: param1}});
});
```